# Importing a Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am facing a weird issue, can someone please help with this. I have a .bacpac file on the Blob storage, the bacpac file size is around 800 MB. This file was created by doing an export from one of the SQL DB on Azure which is of 4 GB.

While I am trying to import the .bacpac file, only the DB schema is created in the new database, data in the tables is missing. Can someone please suggest with this.

Many thanks

Comment: Try downloading the bacpac file and importing via SSMS 2014, this will output any errors it runs into and help narrow the issue down.

Comment: Getting frequent out of memory issue while importing the bacpac to local machine. I have 4 GB free, but still this error :(

Comment: Ok, make sure you have the newest DacFX: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898 From there try SQLPackage.exe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) with the storage option set to File.

Comment: Are you trying to import the backup from the portal or by some other way?

Answer (score 1):

**Create a New Database by Importing BACPAC File**

Log on to the Azure Management Portal.
Click New > Data Services > SQL Database > Import. ...
Click the folder under BACPAC URL to navigate to the Storage Account, Container, and file name of the exported .bacpac file. ...
Specify a name for the new SQL database.

This works perfectly without any issues.